# How to compile c++ libs using Microsoft C++ compiler without the IDE

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to use Notepad and invoke the compiler and linker from the command prompt.
No IDE no make , nmake or anything like similar because I want to know the exact syntax required to do the following:
1. create a static library
2. create a dll
Yes, I have browsed the MSDN site but the examples I saw assume one is using the IDE which does a lot of setup behind the scenes
Pls Note: I know how to compile executables using cl also setting up the env using vcvarsall.bat. My question is about compiling static libraries and dlls.

I am using Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86.
Suggestions on to use some other compiler ( gcc, mingw, intel etc.) will not be helpful at the moment.

Comment: Please, please look into using an editor other than Notepad.

Comment: @user: I recommend [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html)

Comment: @robert. I know, point taken. I wanted to make it clear that I don't want 'helpful' development environment for this learning exercise. Actually I use Notepda++.

Comment: There really is no point in using a Microsoft compiler to achieve this goal.  You are much better off with doing this with GCC.  There's an active community to help you step you through the excruciatingly boring details of getting all the command line options right.

Comment: @Hans: Hm... why is there no point in using an MS compiler?  e.g. I've created a batch file that calls `cl` and `link` to compile a C programs, and I regularly use it to compile small programs from text editor. It's been pretty useful so far... not sure why you say it's not.

Comment: That would have been pretty useful with a gcc compiler as well.  Compilers are a dime-a-dozen, use the one that works for you.  And can get the most support with, that's the one that really counts.

Comment: @Hans: Interesting, ok. The script actually works for GCC too (as well  for the 2003 DDK, which is pretty awesome at linking with `msvcrt.dll`). But making it was definitely painful; support is definitely important as well.

Comment: I know that you have explicitly requested not to get make/nmake and similar tools but I don't understand why: you can use those tools and see the command line for the calls that they make to the compiler/linker

Comment: @David Rodríguez. AFAIK In order to use make and similar tools effectively you need to have familiarity with the compiler and linker commands and options that need to be invoked by make, no?

Comment: @user754425: Or you can use a higher level make program like CMake to generate those for you, and then read the generated commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DLLs, pass the `/c` flag to `cl.exe` (which compiles but doesn't link), and pass the `/DLL` flag to `link.exe`. Instead of making an executable, it makes a DLL.

For static libraries, [use the `lib.exe` program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: You have a better more relevant answer than James McNellis who seems to have more votes for some reason. I don't know how this voting works

Comment: Is the flag /DLL supposed to produce a lib file automatically or there are additional flags to enable that to happen? How do you instruct the link to output a lib file AND a dll?

Comment: @user754425: I forgot to say, the `/LD` flag to the *compiler* is also used in creating a DLL; `/LD` implies passing `/DLL` to the linker, IIRC. Also, to create a `.lib` file, use the `lib myObjFile.obj` command; it's not created automatically AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ compiler is named **cl**.  The compiler options are [well-documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx).  The linker is named **link**.  The linker options are also [well-documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2fck18t.aspx).

You'll need to run **vcvarsall.bat** to be able to build with the Visual C++ toolchain; this batch file sets up all the required environment variables and such.  If you've installed Visual Studio, you should have a shortcut on your Start Menu entitled "Visual Studio Command Prompt."  This shortcut will get you a command prompt and run that batch file.

Comment: I have seen those options. I have no trouble compiling executables. I am looking for options for creating static libraries and dlls.

Comment: For static libraries, you'll also need `LIB.EXE`, the library manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches, all of which are handily documented in one place:

[Visual C++ Concepts: Building a C/C++ Program

**Building on the Command Line**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Note that the build system completely changed between VC++ 2008 (which you're using) and VC++ 2010 (which is the current release).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of minor things to add.

Personally I wouldn't use Windows batch files.
I would use nmake http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha(v=vs.71).aspx building outside of visual studio is nmake's day job and that's the standard way to build visual studio projects for release say on a build machine, rather than in a development environment.

The other thing in nmake's favour is that if cross-platform is important to you then cmake ( http://www.cmake.org/ ) is a brilliant tool for dynamically creating Windows nmake files and non-Windows make files and it comes with ctest for running your unittests and selftests.

Advert over.